# google-apps-script random link generator

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a problem on hand, which I can´t figure out myself.
In order to write my thesis I need to make a survey. More precisley: I need one for my control and one for my treatment group. I´m using Google Form.

I could not find a way to randomize sections in Forms itself, so I looked at the script editor. I try to find out, if there is a way to have two Forms, which will be randomly assigned to a participant, when clicking on the link.

I thought of something like:

```
function random_2(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random())
    var link1="http://www.google1.com"
    var link2="http://www.google2.com"
        if (myrandom==0)
        window.location=link1
    else if (myrandom==1)
        window.location=link2

}
```

Problem is I´m very unexpirienced in coding and it seems so far noone wanted to do such thing! But there must be an easy way to do so. 
I would very much appreciate any input!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a URL assigned to a user, either A or B, when the *click the link?* If that's the case, you can't. You *can*, however, have a list of participants and randomly assign a link in a spreadsheet down a column.

Something like this would work:

```js
// Generate a random number and return a link
function assignRand() {
  var int = Math.round(Math.random() * 2)
  if(int == 0) {
    return "link1"
  } else {
    return "link2"
  }
}

// Loop through a list of names, emails (whatever) in col A
// Assign a random link to each
function write() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet7")
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var link = assignRand()
    sheet.getRange((i+1), 2).setValue(link)
  }
}
```

Once they're assigned, you could either mail merge to participants or use another apps script function to send individual survey emails within the loop.

Comment: Thank you, Problem is that I intend to use a link. I guess I will have to put up a website just to have a button on it to spread the link ....

Comment: You could do something similar where the link is set randomly at the DOM load for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of links in gs file and then inside doGet() randomly select an array element which will be a link and populate the link in template.

In template you can write client-side javascript code to redirect to that link, or show user a button to redirect to that link.

Will try to update this answer with sample code snippets, when I get some extra time.

You can comment specific question, if you have any.

Comment: to be honest that sounds like somthing that might work, but all the coding I know is ctrl c / v  ;)

Comment: I would love to see your work though if you have a little spare time :)